# First Request, response "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"

Tags: api, directions, google-directions-api

We are experiencing a problem where we have incurred all request

Request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?key=****&units=metricmode=driving&origin=-18.953220736126821,-48.24894517816412&destination=-48.2786408,-18.9218197&

Response:

error_message   "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API."
routes  []
status  "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"

Our metrics haven't reported any issues.  I am curious how and why these errors are being created.

My account is new and is not in production, we're just testing and ours metrics indicate 22 requests...

Comment: did u find any solution i am also stuck here

Comment: yes, you need to link a billing account to the API service

Comment: but it was working fine before that linking..i have not exceeded daily limit..still to gain that free quota do i need to link billing account??

Comment: yes, google changed the rules, you need a billing account ... even being free!